# How can I sort a data in specific form for Interpolation?

Tags: plotting, interpolation, data

I have [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/06i1re8f0e9rjwk/data.dat?dl=0) of closed shape form

```
ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

I would like to Interpolate this data to get the missing points so I am using `BSplineFunction` like this

```
interdata=BSplineFunction[Flatten[points, 1]];
ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

as you can see, the data needs to be sorted in a specific way to make all the points on the circumference of the closed shape and get something like this

[image]

**Update**

The last thing I would like to do is to get points on the circumference that are equally spaced. my idea was that after interpolation I will be able to do that. According to @kglr answer, it can be done  as follows

```
equallyspaceddata = Table[{bsF[t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
ListPlot[equallyspaceddata, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

as you can see the points in the top half are denser compared to the bottom one. How can I get equally spaced points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** *" to get points on the circumference that are equally spaced"*:

Use `MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}` and `Mesh -> m` to get `m` equally-spaced points on the parametric curve:

```
m = 50;

ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}, 
 Mesh -> m, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize @ Medium, Red], 
 Epilog -> {Directive[PointSize @ Medium, Green], Point @ bsF[0]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Use [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html):

```
fcp = FindCurvePath[data];

sorteddata = data[[fcp[[1]]]];

ListLinePlot[sorteddata, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
bsF = BSplineFunction[sorteddata];

ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Try also [`ListCurvePathPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html):

```
ListCurvePathPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: AWESOME, thanks a lot!

Comment: may you please see my update?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the red pint as a list to use them in a calculation?

Comment: @valarmorghulis, one way is to extract the point coordinates from `ParametricPlot`: e.g,, `pp=ParametricPlot[..., MeshFunctions -> {ArcLength}, Mesh ->50]; pointcoords= Cases[Normal@pp, Point[x_] :> x, All]`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/data.dat"];
```

Since you are dealing with a circle:

**EDIT 2:** Using minimization to determine the center and radius

```
{center, radius} = {{x0, y0}, r} /. Minimize[{Total[
      (EuclideanDistance[#, {x0, y0}] - r)^2 & /@ data],
     r > 0}, {x0, y0, r}][[2]]

(* {{-4.22506*10^-14, -4.04645*10^-14}, 0.693182} *)

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   AbsoluteThickness[1], Red,
   Circle[center, radius], Blue,
   Point[CirclePoints[center, radius, n]]}],
 {{n, 51}, 3, 300, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Version 13 has a new function [`RegionFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFit.html)

```
{center, radius} = List @@ RegionFit[data, "Circle"]

(* {{-0.00115749, -9.88079*10^-16}, 0.694887} *)
```

Comment: that is nice, but it is not always a circle, it can be any closed shape such as a rectangle or triangle. for example, your approach cant work with  this [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6vvtrod0kz8syi/data2.dat?dl=0)